# To prove $E_r$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

I came across this theorem which states,

> Let *f*:$R^1$->$R^1$. For any  r>0 let $E_r$ be the set of all $a \in R^1$ such that, $\omega$[*f*;a]$\geq$ 1/r. Then $E_r$ is closed.

Here I am finding it difficult to understand, how do they call $E_r$ to be a closed set under such a condition. In what is it related?

Sorry if my question is not up to the mark.

Comment: Is $\omega$ the oscillation function? What is this?

Comment: @IAmNoOne yes $\omega$ is an oscillation function

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $w(f,x) <\frac  1 r$. Let $w(f,x) <t<\frac  1 r$. Then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(z)-f(y| \leq t$ whenver $y,z \in [x-\delta,x+\delta]$.  If $u \in [x-\delta/2,x+\delta/2]$ then we get $|f(z)-f(y| \leq t$ whenver $y,z \in [u-\delta/2,u+\delta/2]$. It follows that $w(f,u) <\
\frac  1 r$. We have proved that the complement of the given set is  open. Hence the given set is closed.

Comment: Sorry I am asking about the relationship between the given condition and the closed set $E_r$. I am not able to understand in what is it made possible?

Comment: I cannot understand the question 'Ín what is it related'. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I know the required condition for a set to be closed. But  here how do they say $E_r$ is closed by using the condition as mentioned in the theorem above. Please do elaborate!!!

Comment: The proof does not involve any property of the function $f$. It depends only on the definition of $w(f,x)$. I have given a complete proof of th fact that $E_r$ is closed.e